# Columns or rows?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a database with the information regarding various financial parameters of my company (such as revenue, different expenditures, tax, profit, etc.). The number of parameters may be large (depending on interested financial parameters) and new parameters may be added later. The parameters are grouped by date (for each month there are some parameters).

To store this data I have 3 options:

- All the information, related to a specific date, store in one row of a table (lots of columns).
- Group the parameters, for each group use a separate table, in each table store all information related to a specific date in one row (more tables)
- Each parameter for a specific date store in a separate row (lots of rows).

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach and which is the best practice in my case?

Comment: Rule of **thumb** - fewer columns and more rows better! You'd have to provide actual table DDL (`CREATE TABLE foo...`) for us to be able to advise further. p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: @Vérace Could you please share some information regarding this rule of thumb?

Comment: No - afraid not. It is just that - a rule of **thumb** - which means that **on average** over a **large** sample of systems, it is **generally** the better choice - but again, I did ask for your DDL - it's not set in stone, but if I were designing a new system, I would start from fewer columns and more rows and revise from there! It's **normally** more flexible and performant!

Comment: @Leeloo Actually this "rule of thumb" is what the whole point of normalization is (as linked in my answer), and [**star schema**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema) is a style of design that confirms to normalization. Please read into my link on normalization for more information on the "rule of thumb".

Comment: If all the names of the parameters are known in advance, I would define them as columns with one row for each date/month. But if the parameters are dynamic, it might be easier to add them as rows -- adding columns requires DDL, locking to execute, and may be expensive if there are lots of rows in the table. And it may require business approval to make these sorts of changes making it more difficult to make these kinds of changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a relational database management system (RDBMS), **PostgreSQL**, then you should use a [**normalized**](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html) relational structure to maximize performance and reduce data redundancy which improves your database's maintainability.

So you should basically do what you describe in your second option. Break out related fields into their own tables, and it sounds like `Date` will be your **key** (or at least should have an **index** on it).

Your first option is **denormalized** and will make your tables unnecessarily large and not performant, in addition to potentially having **data duplication**.

Your third option is more **destructured** and suitable for a **NoSQL** database, but wouldn't be efficient or manageable for querying in **PostgreSQL**.

Comment: I like the third option, because adding a new parameter is cheap. In the second (or first) option you have to add a new column, what would be quite expensive in case of large amounts of data. What do you think?

Comment: @Leeloo: adding a new (nullable) column is a matter of milliseconds regardless of the size of the table

Comment: @Leeloo I don't know what you consider large amounts of data, but I've worked with tables that had 10s of billions of rows and were 1.5 TB big per table, in financial tech (so we were constantly adding new data points, ergo new columns / lots of schema changes). The second option (what I recommended in my answer) is what worked best, all around.

Comment: @Leeloo Also, from an optimization of management performance perspective for large tables, you should look into [**Table Partitioning**](https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-use-table-partitioning-scale-postgresql#).

Comment: @J.D. The point is, I'm not sure which parameters (columns) would be required ın the near future (but they will be required for sure). So, if I add later new columns and update subsequent rows to add data there, this would be quite expensive operation. However, the third option deals with this very well.

Comment: So, the question is, is the third option worse than the second and how much? What are the disadvantages? Performance?

Comment: @Leeloo I think you missed my point and a_horse_with_no_name's that adding a new column is not an expensive operation. And updating that new column isn't any more expensive than your third solution (since at the end of the day, the same amount of data has to be modified). Structured properly with the correct indexes for your second design option will ensure the updating of new columns will be very performant actually. The drawbacks of using the third option is it's more cumbersome and will likely be slower to query against if you ever need to read more than one property of a Date at a time.